# Would not 'armistice' be a better word to use than 'pause' in present discussions of 'ceasefire'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, etymology

In the current situation, there are calls for a 'ceasefire' and calls for a 'pause'.

> Humanitarian pauses and ceasefires – what are the differences?

[Chatham House org](https://www.chathamhouse.org/2023/11/humanitarian-pauses-and-ceasefires-what-are-differences)

But there exists a better word than 'pause' which I think is being wrongly used.

The word was used on Friday on '*Have I Got News for You*', BBC 1, by Ian Hislop, the Editor of Private Eye. Mr Hislop used it in connection with the present situation and also related to the Day of celebration, yesterday.

> Armistice, truce, and ceasefire have been used at different periods with varying degrees of overlap. In current international law, **armistice is more narrowly defined** than truce and ceasefire, in being a temporary (**but total**) **suspension of hostilities** by agreement between the governments of warring parties, normally (but not necessarily) for the purposes of negotiation. **A total surrender may also be described as an armistice for legal purposes.** Cf. ceasefire n. 2.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/armistice_n?tab=meaning_and_use#39231914)

> 2009
> Achieving an armistice was one thing; restoring peace was quite another.
> G. R. Berridge, British Diplomacy in Turkey vi. 128Citation details for G. R. Berridge, British Diplomacy in Turkey

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/armistice_n?tab=meaning_and_use#39231914)

*Having just celebrated Armistice Day*, should the word not be used as being better defined to the purpose than 'pause' . . . . .  or even 'ceasefire' ?

---

It is an agreement to **cease to be hostile** to one another, at least until agreements can be negotiated towards **a permanent solution**.

---

Comment: An armistice is an agreement to cease _hostilities_, not merely to cease _fighting_.

Comment: Is your question whether "humanitarian pause" and "armistice" mean different things?

Comment: "Pause" is used specifically to refer to a minimal break, both by those who want war but recognise the need for a short break, and more derisively by those who want a permanent peace to criticise those calling for 4-hour truces. Ceasefire means fairly obviously to stop shooting, so it seems apt. Armistice is more legalistic and hence less emotive, but also perhaps more final than ceasefire which is often temporary, so it suits neither side. (And the purpose of a pause would be humanitarian.) But if you're asking why terms are used by politicians your question probably belongs on Politics SE.

Comment: 'Total surrender' seems a lot more final than 'temporary (but total) suspension of hostilities', so OED is saying the term is ill-defined. Stipulative definitions would be necessary for meaningful usage, but as I read the OED excerpt, current international law doesn't clarify. If these august bodies don't, the word remains suspect.

Comment: Notwithstanding what the dictionary definitions may say about the meaning of *armistice*, most people nowadays encounter that word only when reading about the historical events that took place some considerable time ago; the term has acquired a certain old-time feel and is rarely used for anything that may happen nowadays.

Comment: Consider that Armistice Day celebrates the *end* of World War I. Regardless of what the dictionary says, most people will equate it with a truce or victory by one side.